# unexpected token : on ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Got an issue with my ajax, Here is my code

```
var sortTable = function() {

  $("#tableid tbody tr").detach().sort(function(a, b) {

    var dataA = $(a).find("td:eq(3)").text().trim();

    var dataB = $(b).find("td:eq(3)").text().trim();

    return parseFloat(dataA.substring(1)) - parseFloat(dataB.substring(

      1));

    }).appendTo('#tableid');

  };

  // var contentType ="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
  //
  // if(window.XDomainRequest) contentType = "text/plain";


  $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (xhr){
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    },
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'Url here' + var,
    success: function(json) {
      //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) {
        var section = json.results[i].name;
        var tid = json.results[i].Id.slice(1);
        var price = json.results[i].minPrice;
        var url = json.results[i].url;
        var button =
        "<a class='btn btn-info'>Buy Now</a>";
        $("#tableid").append("<tr><td><img id='theImg' src='/assets/logo.png'/></td><td><b>" + section +
        "</b></td><td><b> In Stock </b></td><td><b>£" + price + "</b></td><td><b>N/A</b></td><td><b>£" + price +"</b></td><td><b>" + button + "</b></td></tr>");
        $("#tableid").find(".btn.btn-info").click(function() {
          location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
        });
      }
      sortTable();
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
```

Now when i try and load the thing (debuggers in both the error and the success) the debugger activates in the error function, Stating that its status 200 etc etc. (the data is pulled back fine in postman)

In the console i get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

How can i fix this? obviously nothing being appended to the table because of this.

Sam

Comment: I am suspecting this line: `url: 'Url here' + var`. `var` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: See [JavaScript errors reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516880/javascript-errors-reference-what-does-this-error-mean/34516940#34516940).

Comment: var is just an example that was there. its not really called var, ITs just something else, Besides that would throw another error

Comment: There's a good chance you're missing a comma or that there's some other syntax error that you haven't noticed, and didn't copy into this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JSONP, the response should be valid JavaScript code, like this:

```
callback({a: 1, b: 2});
```

while in your case it's probably:

```
{a: 1, b: 2}
```

Comment: Yes its coming back as json, However if i place it in as json datatype, It gives me another error which is XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL HERE. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: How would i do that? place these either side of the url?

Comment: Its a api link , not a static json file unfortunatly

Comment: Its just being called via the url field? im not generating it

Comment: then just being appended to the table, via the table id